# Can't see how this can be true: any connected undirected graph $G$ contains vertex v such that removing v results in another connected Graph $G'$

Tags: graphs

I am attempting to prove this result but I found a case where I can easily disprove this statement.

> Suppose $G$ is a graph with two nodes u, v and an edge (u,v) and respective self edges, then removing the edge u,v results in two nodes left, therefore leaving the resulting graph disconnected.

[image]

Can someone show me why I am approaching this question incorrectly?

Comment: Your chosen title and question text don't match. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that removing any vertex of a finite graph $G$ would disconnect it. Then $G$ could not contain any cycles (else we'd have an immediate contradiction) and so $G$ would have to be a tree. However, removing a leaf vertex of $G$ wouldn't disconnect it, contrary again to our assumption.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the last sentence, what is the assumption here? That G is not a tree?

Comment: @MathNewb. The assumption is that removing any vertex of $G$ would disconnect it. Clearly that's not true if $G$ is a tree.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks you to remove a *vertex* rather than an edge. Also, undirected graphs usually don't have self-loops, and in the context of undirected graphs, undirected edges are usually not thought of as consisting of two directed edges, but rather as being indivisible.

In your example, removing either A or B results in a connected graph.

Comment: I clearly read "removing the edge u,v" in the question.

Comment: @Raphael Perhaps you should also read the title of the question.

Comment: In case of doubt, question texts take priority (as a general SE rule). I agree that the OP should clarify.

Comment: @Raphael The question text highlights a doubt that the OP had about the actual question. It complements the question in the title by giving a counterexample. The highlighted text is the counterexample rather than the original question.